# Sockets performance and overhead

Tags: php, sockets

Which of these two socket connectivity options are more efficient to use, in terms of having better performance and less overhead?

[socket_connect](http://www.php.net/socket_connect) family or [fsockopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the performance is very much the same, but the result of the connection is different after initialization. For example `fsockopen()` will open the connection and immediately go to `LISTENING`-state, where `socket_create()` will just create the connection and `socket_open()` put it in `LISTENING`-state.

You could say: `fsockopen() === socket_open(socket_create(), ADDRESS)`

Furthermore, after you do `socket_shutdown()` and `socket_close()`, you will leave the connection in `TIME_WAIT`-state, which will will make the socket wait until the receiving end of the socket disconnects, which can take a while.

All in all, there quite the same, choose the one you like the best and suits your intention best. If you want to pre-create all sockets but only connect in a certain time, go with `socket_create()`, else use `fsockopen()` as it's easier.

*If you have your own webserver and no intention of distributing your code, you can also take a look into cURL, which is essentially the same as both other options but has more failsaves built-in.*

Comment: Thanks, cURL support UDP connections?

Comment: If you want to setup UDP connection(s) I would stick with either fsockopen or socket_open, since cURL is originally designed for certain protocols (like HTTP, FTP, TELNET, etc.) and not really custom data.